# Textarea validation in Angular4 and symfony3

Tags: angular, typescript, symfony-3.3

I'm using angular 4 and symfony3, I have a textarea witch is required. Bu I if press only an enter **(code 13)** in this textarea without any other character , the form is submitted. How can I prevent this ?

this is typeScript code:

```
createFormControls() {
    this.commentContent = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
}
```

and this is symfony code:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="content is empty")
 *
 * @Serializer\Groups({"details"})
 */
private $content;
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more of code, how are you binding **commentContent**?

Answer (score 0):

in model driven forms it must be works,you do like this

```
this.importsshkeyForm = this.fb.group({
        'text_area_control':['',[Validators.required]]
    });
```